# Metodo registro no se realiza PHP

Tags: base-de-datos, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

espero alguien pueda ayudarme con el siguiente detalle.
Antes que nada colocare el codigo. Sucede que, una vez que doy clic en guardar, no me marca error, si no que el navegador se queda en el controlador -registrar- y no hace mas. No se que detalle debo tener por ahi. Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de revisar mi problema.

**Modelo**

```
    public function guardarC(
    $CURP, $nombre, $ap_P, $ap_M, $num_tel, $id_localidad, $id_colonia, 
    $referencia) {

    $ciudadano = array(
        'CURP'         => $CURP,
        'nombre'       => $nombre,
        'ap_P'         => $ap_P,
        'ap_M'         => $ap_M,
        'num_tel'      => $num_tel,
        'id_localidad' => $id_localidad,
        'id_colonia'   => $id_colonia,
        'referencia'   => $referencia,
    );
    $this->db->insert('cat_ciudadanos', $ciudadano);
}
```

**Controlador**

```
    public function registrar()
{
    if ($this->input->post('submit')) {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('CURP', 'CURP', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nombre', 'nombre', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ap_P', 'ap_P', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ap_M', 'ap_M', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('num_tel', 'num_tel', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_localidad', 'id_localidad', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_colonia', 'id_colonia', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('referencia', 'referencia', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
            $CURP         = $_POST['CURP'];
            $nombre       = $_POST['nombre'];
            $ap_P         = $_POST['ap_P'];
            $ap_M         = $_POST['ap_M'];
            $num_tel      = $_POST['num_tel'];
            $id_localidad = $_POST['id_localidad'];
            $id_colonia   = $_POST['id_colonia'];
            $referencia   = $_POST['referencia'];

            $datos = $this->Registros_model->guardarC(
                $CURP,
                $nombre,
                $ap_P,
                $ap_M,
                $num_tel,
                $id_localidad,
                $id_colonia,
                $referencia
            );

            redirect('ayuntamiento/registroC', 'refresh');
        }
    }
}
```

**Vista**

```
<div class="container">
<form id="form" name="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>ayuntamiento/registrar">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="CURP">C U R P</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="CURP" placeholder="C U R P">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
             <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre (s)">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ap_P">Primer Apellido</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ap_P" placeholder="Apellido Paterno">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ap_M">Segundo Apellido</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ap_M" placeholder="Apellido Materno">
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="telefono">Numero Telefonico</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="num_tel" placeholder="Numero Telefonico">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Dirección</label>
            <br>
            <select  class="form-control" id="id_localidad" name="id_localidad" style="background-color: #A9A9A9">
                <option value="0">Localidades</option>
                <?php foreach ($localidades as $i) {?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $i->id_localidad; ?>"><?php echo $i->nombre; ?></option>;
                <?php }?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="id_colonia" name="id_colonia" style="background-color: #A9A9A9">
                <option value="0">Colonias</option>
                <?php foreach ($colonias as $i) {?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $i->id_colonia; ?>"><?php echo $i->nombre; ?></option>;
                <?php }?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="referencia">Referencia</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="referencia"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="container">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Guardar
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace tiempo que no uso *Codeigniter*, pero en tu controlador el primer if

```
if($this->input->post('submit')){
   ...
```

devolvería *NULL*, el cual es un valor **falsy**, porque no existe ningún `input` en tu formulario que tenga por nombre submit. Por lo cual nunca se ejecuta el contenido del if. Más info sobre el library [`input`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::post)

Si lo que quieres es saber si el formulario fue enviado por *POST* deberías preguntar así:

```
if ($this->input->method() === 'post') {
```

Saludos.